# New line in data retrieved from database to jsp

Tags: java, html, css, database, jsp

I am trying to create a web page using **JSP**, the main page return and display the date from the database to JSP file and there is an edit button that allows to edit the message and therefore edit the data in the database,  I have modified the text that shows the main page by declaring
`String convert = rs.getString("template");` then print `convert`  but when I clicked **edit** the text appears as it comes from database although the text contains br tag ; it displays without new line.

here the run for the main page

[image]

here the run for edit page

[image]

I tried to change the way to fetch the data as shown in img No. 3, but it did not work for me either

[image: img3]
**My question is how I can insert a new line in this case?**

the code run as it is meant to be, there is just this display issue.
here is the code for Edit.JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
    pageEncoding="windows-1256" import="java.io.*" import="java.sql.*"
    import="java.util.*" import="javax.sql.*"%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <%
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-SQ7B6EQ;databaseName=JsonToSql";

    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection con = null;

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    %>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <%
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String u = request.getParameter("u");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(u);
        String data = "select * from DatabaseMsgs where id = '" + num + "' ";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(data);

        while (rs.next()) {
        %>


        <h3 align="left"
            style="Color: white; font-size: 18px; color: black; font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;">
            Welcome to edit page</h3>
        <input class="container" type="hidden" name="id"
            value="<%=rs.getString("id")%>">
        <table border="0">
            <tr align="left"
                style="font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Festive', curesultive; text-transform: capitalize; font-size: 15px; color: #203bd6">
                <td>code:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="code"
                    value='<%=rs.getString("code")%>' /></td>
            </tr>
        <%--    <%
            String convert = rs.getString("template").replaceAll("EmployeeName:", "Employee Name:")
                    .replaceAll("Luc", "Lucation").replaceAll("TelephoneNo", "Telephone No.").replaceAll("E-mail", "E-mail:")
                    .replaceAll("Mobile", "Mobile No. : ").replaceAll("phoneExtension", "phone Extension No.:")
                    .replaceAll("[* \\  ----------------------- ]", " ").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
            %> --%>
            <tr align="left">
                <td
                    style="font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Festive', curesultive; text-transform: capitalize; font-size: 15px; color: #203bd6">template:</td>


                <td><input  type="text" style="width: 100ch; height: 30ch;"
                    name="template" value='<%=rs.getString("template")%>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left" valign="top">
                <td></td>

                <%
                }
                %>
                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<%
String a = request.getParameter("id");
String b = request.getParameter("code");
String c = request.getParameter("template");

if (a != null && b != null && c != null) {

    String query = "update DatabaseMsgs set code = ? , template=? where id = '" + a + "' ";
    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, b);
    ps.setString(2, c);

    ps.executeUpdate();
    response.sendRedirect("Home.jsp");
}

    %>
```

`

Comment: Can you inspect the element not being displayed on new line and share the image on your question?

Comment: Can you try ```\n``` instead of ```<br>``` as it's not clear where exactly you are trying to add a new line.

Comment: @skr I tried to use  \n instead of br tag but it did not work.
as you can see in the attached img No.1 , these is the format I want my text to be like.
Employee Name: <br>
Mobile No. : <br>

Comment: @skr also I try to use ` rs.getString("template").replaceAll("<br>" , "\n")` ,  but it did not work also :(

Comment: If I understand clearly, you want  the string with ```<br>``` inside the template field in edit page to be displayed in new line?

Comment: @skr yes that correct

Comment: check my answer below, it will solve your issue, if solved please, accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML input elements, type text or something similar (such as email) will deliberately strip off all line breaks, so that’s not going to work.

The only form element which will accept line breaks is the textarea.

also, instead of using `<br>` or `'\n'` use `&#13;&#10;` at place where you want to add new line

So, instead of using ,

`<input type="text" name="test" value='<%=convert %>'/>`

**use**

`<textarea cols='60' rows='8' va> <%=convert %> </textarea>`

**For Ex:**

`<textarea cols='30' rows='2' va>This is my statement one.&#13;&#10;This is my statement2</textarea>`

**will result in**

[image]

You can adjust the height and width of textarea by adjusting the `cols` and `rows`.

**To make it more look like a input field**,

**try this,**

```js
function auto_height(elem) { 
    elem.style.height = "1px";
    elem.style.height = (elem.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
```

```css
.auto_height { /* CSS */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="2" class="auto_height" oninput="auto_height(this)">line1&#13;&#10line2</textarea>
```

Comment: yes, It's working now ... thank you so much

Comment: Great, please upvote and accept my answer.